# One checkbox checking others

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox

I want to have one checkbox that will check all others and I'm stuck. I'm trying to do that with a loop but that returns nothing.

It's an exercise so I cant change the html ids.

HTML:

```
       <p>
        Price for adds: <span id="price">0 usd</span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <form>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox">All adds</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="3.50">Additional cheese, 3,50 USD</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="2.20">Salami, 2,20 USD</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="5.00">Additional Ham, 5 USD</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="4.10">pepper, 4,10 USD</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="3.50">Mushroms, 3,50 USD</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox">Clear all</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <p>
                <button class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

        $('.panel-body').on('change','input',function(e){


           if($(this).parent().text()=='All adds'){
                var inps = $('.checkbox input');

                    $(inps).each(function{
                        $(this).prop('checked', true)
                    })


                var price = $('#price').html()
                price = price.replace("USD", "");
                price = parseFloat(price)
                var add = $(this).attr('data-price')

                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    console.log($(this).text())
                    var totalPrice = parseFloat(add) + parseFloat(price)

                    $('#price').html(totalPrice.toFixed(2))
                }
                else {
                    var totalPrice =  parseFloat(price) - parseFloat(add)
                    $('#price').html(totalPrice.toFixed(2))
                }
        })


})
```

Comment: were is your JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: `$(inps).each(function{` should be   `$(inps).each(function(){`

Comment: But also it's very bizarre to have a clear all checkbox.

Comment: got it now guys thx for tips and help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st you are missing `()` after function:

```
  $(inps).each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
  })
```

2nd use `trim()` to remove whitespace from both sides`$(this).parent().text().trim()`

3rd the `if` you have is closed with `)}` which is wrong, just use `)`

4th Instead of using `each` you can just do `$('.checkbox input').prop('checked', true)`:

```
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('.checkbox input').prop('checked', true)
  } else {
    $('.checkbox input').prop('checked', false)
  }
```

This allowed you to uncheck all as well.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.panel-body').on('change', 'input', function(e) {

    if ($(this).parent().text().trim() == 'All adds') {

      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.checkbox input').prop('checked', true)
      } else {
        $('.checkbox input').prop('checked', false)
      }

      var price = $('#price').html()
      price = price.replace("USD", "");
      price = parseFloat(price)
      var add = $(this).attr('data-price')

      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        console.log($(this).text())
        var totalPrice = parseFloat(add) + parseFloat(price)

        $('#price').html(totalPrice.toFixed(2))
      } else {
        var totalPrice = parseFloat(price) - parseFloat(add)
        $('#price').html(totalPrice.toFixed(2))
      }
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    Price for adds: <span id="price">0 usd</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class='panel'>
  <div class='panel-body'>
    <form>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox">All adds</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-price="3.50">Additional cheese, 3,50 USD</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-price="2.20">Salami, 2,20 USD</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-price="5.00">Additional Ham, 5 USD</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-price="4.10">pepper, 4,10 USD</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-price="3.50">Mushroms, 3,50 USD</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox">Clear all</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>
        <button class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Marduuk check my updated answer, hope it helps, also allowed you to uncheck all when you click the checked All option.

Comment: Thanks for help that helped me alot <3

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
$(inps).each(function{
                        $(this).prop('checked', true)
                    })
```

You should change this:
`$(inps).each(function{`

To this:
`$(inps).each(function(){`

Answer (score -1):

Give your main checkbox an id "cAll". and use jQuery:

```
    $("#cAll").click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

Comment: I know, with a proud down vode. Pleasure it helped.